# Is it necessary to call Looper.prepare() from within the UI thread?

Tags: android, android-activity, handler, looper

If I want to implement a Handler object from within my Activity's main thread, do I need to call Looper.prepare() beforehand, or do activities already have their own internal loopers?  Does the same hold true if I want to instantiate a Handler instance from within a Service?

Answer (score 0):

The main thread already has its own looper. See [`Context.getMainLooper()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getMainLooper%28%29). The main thread encompasses all Activities and Services in the application.